# Construction of a plasma model

Tags: plasma-physics

I would like to start to build a plasma model. Though Beginning is posing a struggle. What is the simplest way to go about modelling a plasma?
Are there any tricks to it?

Answer (score 0):

M.J. Kushner has a useful (albeit old) [presentation](http://uigelz.eecs.umich.edu/pub/presentations/mjk_gec99a_models.pdf) that discusses modelling a plasma "from scratch".  This is assuming you want to model the plasma computationally (not analytically).  His website also has other very helpful presentations, mini-courses, and publications on this same topic.